# update php mysql val+5

Tags: php, mysql, sql

can you help me please, I whant to update my table to add x points to the value :

```
$Fr_Points = 5;
$Fr_Descri = "Un avis a été donné";
$EN_PDO = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ".$TB_USER_REPORT_STATS." SET Points = Points+".$Fr_Points.", Description=:Fr_Descri WHERE Pseudo='".$Fr_Pseudo."' ");
$EN_PDO->bindParam(":Fr_Points",        $Fr_Points);
$EN_PDO->bindParam(":Fr_Descri",        $Fr_Descri);
$EN_PDO->execute();
```

But I get an error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /xxx/xxx/www/login/avis.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /xxx/xxx/www/login/avis.php(61): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /xxx/xxx/www/login/avis.php on line 61
```

Can you help me please ?
Cordialy

Comment: Go research the error message. Go read up on how PDO queries with parameters actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix concatination with prepared statements:

```
$EN_PDO = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ".$TB_USER_REPORT_STATS." SET Points = Points+:Fr_Points, Description=:Fr_Descri WHERE Pseudo=:Fr_Pseudo ");

$EN_PDO->bindParam(":Fr_Points",        $Fr_Points);
$EN_PDO->bindParam(":Fr_Descri",        $Fr_Descri);
$EN_PDO->bindParam(":Fr_Pseudo",        $Fr_Pseudo);
$EN_PDO->execute();
```

Every named placeholder must have an equivalent in and bind Statement and visa via

Comment: I dont understand this :
Points = Point= :Fr_Points

Comment: @Jaber sorry my fault. Have changed it